# Python script that is linked to an excel sheet and checks when a condition is true

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to write a python script that is linked to an ever updating excel sheet with lists of temperatures. We have stations in 15 countries that take record ocean/atmospheric temperatures at 10 min intervals and sends them to us, it runs 24/7/365. The excel file is 10 columns wide and several thousand rows long, every 10 minutes there is a new row with new numbers. We are concerned when the difference between the temps changes too quickly or too slowly and we continuously check it by hand. We have several dozen conditions that we are constantly monitoring and checking by hand, usually just checking the latest row in a column to see if its in a certain (2 degree) range from a row that is 50 or 100 or 1000 rows above the latest row. Has anyone worked with anything similar? I would basically like to write a script that is always running and checking is several conditions are true. I would like to be able to just write the 40 or 50 conditions into the script and anytime one of the conditions is TRUE i would get a notifications such as 'Condition number 8 is now true'. Any suggestions on python libraries or books that I can use that are specifically for this purpose?

Comment: How is the Excel file updated? Do you have some script that merges files from the 15 stations and updates the Excel file on the fly? An Excel file using some kind of Microsoft collaborative sharing thingy that people edit from each station? Or… what?

Comment: Im not exactly sure, I just know that if i open it an 14:19:59 it will have x number of rows, if I open it at 14:20:01 it will have x+1 number of rows. It is just a regular .xls file. Every time minutes it gets updated with a a new row of prices.

Comment: The data might be coming from a "data connection"- in Excel 2010, you can check this by going to the Data tab and clicking "Connections"- it's probably a good idea to find out exactly where your data is coming from to see if you can get at it more directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, it sounds like your system would be far better if it was a webapp backed by an actual database. This would be trivial to create based on your problem description so far. That aside, this looks like what you want: http://www.python-excel.org/

Run your script with a cron job (or scheduled task if your on windows) and you should be golden.

Comment: Thank you. We use mac computers, do you know if that makes a difference? Also, off the top of your head, do you know any good 'webapp backed by an actual database' manuals?

Comment: Python is cross platform, and Mac's have cron, so it should not be an issue. If you are comfortable with python, I recommend: https://www.djangoproject.com/ -- Django is an easy to use web framework with extremely good documentation and tutorials. Otherwise you would be fine with: php, asp, node.js, ruby, etc... One thing that I came across that may make it easier: http://www.jtable.org/ -- this makes it really easy to build "table" style CRUD (create/read/update/delete) apps.